# Comparing user input against mysql db values in Python

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, comparison, mysql-python

I'm new to Python and MySQL. I created a MySQL db 'food' in localhost.
I want to write a python code to take user input and compare it against fruits 
column in my database file. If the input string matches any value in database
it must print "Item Exists" else add the string to the database.

`mysql> select * from example;
+----+--------+
| id | fruits |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Apple  |
|  2 | Orange |
|  3 | Grape  |
+----+--------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)`

I know how to access the db and insert values to it, but not how to compare it with user input. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: You said you can access the db, what are you doing to try to retrieve values from it?

Comment: @Eqomatic i use `fetchall()`. Here :- `cursor.execute("SELECT fruits FROM example") x=cursor.fetchall()`. I don't know how use values in x to compare with user input.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment:

```
fruits = cursor.fetchall()
for fruit in fruits:
    if input == fruit:
        print("Item exists")
```

Comment: it compares user input only with the first row not with the others.
Is there any other better way to do that like storing all the values in the column in a single row as multiple values and accessing it for further process as list of strings?

Comment: `for fruit in fruits:` loops over all rows in the fruits column, assuming that `fetchall()` returns all values as a list.